# Drop down List from Viewbag not following selected property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a dropdownList that will be populated by a viewbag carrying a List values containing "Text" and "Value" property that is set by a loop.

```
      List<SelectListItem> year = new List<SelectListItem>();


        for (var i = 1990; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
        {
            year.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.ToString(),
                Value = i.ToString()
            });
        }

       ViewBag.Year = year;
```

And in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, new SelectList(ViewBag.Year, "Value", "Text", Model.Birthday.Year), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 80px" })
```

Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, new SelectList(@ViewBag.Year, "Value", "Text", Model.Birthday.Year), new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 80px" })
```

It will work as expected.

Comment: It is working perfectly may be there is something wrong at controller actionmethod.

Comment: I wrote a Jquery function instead. It's okay now

Answer (score 0):

I used script instead

```js
    $('#Year option')
     .removeAttr('selected')
     .filter('[value=@Model.Birthday.Year]')
         .attr('selected', true)
```